# How to analyze a curvilinear relation

Tags: regression, curve-fitting

How should I go about analyzing a relation between 2 variables that seem to be related to each other in a curvilinear manner.

For example, the heartrate dataset in drc package for R software has pressure and rate related to each other as shown below:

```
library(drc)

head(heartrate)
  pressure   rate
1    50.85 348.76
2    54.92 344.45
3    59.23 343.05
4    61.91 332.92
5    65.22 315.31
6    67.79 313.50

plot(heartrate)
```

[image]

There appears to be curvilinear relation between 2 variables.

What are the general steps to analyze such data?

Edit: I am specifically looking for methods where I do not have to initially guess the relation.

Comment: There are many Q&As that deal with this on stackoverflow, here's one, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15050715/1036500

Comment: I am specifically looking for methods where I do not have to initially guess the relation.

Comment: See the section on 'Genetic Programming' in the answer I linked to above.

Comment: What do you intend "analyze" to include? Is this simply a matter of estimation?

Comment: I want to determine the simplest curve (with its equation) that best fits the data.  I know there are a number of sites for curve-fitting but is there a good method where I do not have to specify the function (equation) myself?